# Use regex to search for a phrase where the last word has a maximum number of characters

Tags: python, regex

So I have a list of words below:

```py
list = ['cyber attacks, 28','cyber attacks. A', 'cyber attacks, intrusions', 'cyber attacks; 3','cyber attack. Our', 'cyber intrusions, data']
```

What I want to do is to remove the phrases in the list if the third word has more than three characters. So the final list would be:

```py
new_list = ['cyber attacks, 28','cyber attacks. A', 'cyber attacks; 3','cyber attack. Our']
```

This is what I have so far but it also includes the phrases where the last word is more than three characters:

```py
new_list = []

for phrase in list:
    max_three_char = re.match('cyber\s\w{1,}(\.|,|;|\)|\/|:|"|])\s\w{,3}', phrase)
    if max_three_char:
        new_list.append(phrase)
```

Comment: Are you separating by comma? Ie is `cyber attacks, 28` two words or three?

Comment: Hi Jan, so ```cyber attacks, 28``` would be considered as three words. The punctuation is just "part of the second word".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
import re 

li = ['cyber attacks, 28','cyber attacks. A', 'cyber attacks, intrusions', 'cyber attacks; 3','cyber attack. Our', 'cyber intrusions, data']

>>> [s for s in li if re.search(r'(?<=\W)\w{1,3}$', s)]
['cyber attacks, 28', 'cyber attacks. A', 'cyber attacks; 3', 'cyber attack. Our']
```

Or if you can count on have a space delimiter:

```
>>> [s for s in li if len(s.split()[-1])<=3]
# same
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension as in

```
import re

lst = ['cyber attacks, 28','cyber attacks. A', 'cyber attacks, intrusions', 'cyber attacks; 3','cyber attack. Our', 'cyber intrusions, data']
pattern = re.compile(r'[, ]+')

new_lst = [item
           for item in lst
           for splitted in [pattern.split(item)]
           if not (len(splitted) > 2 and len(splitted[2]) > 3)]

print(new_lst)
```

Which would yield

```
['cyber attacks, 28', 'cyber attacks. A', 'cyber attacks; 3', 'cyber attack. Our']
```

Don't name your variables after built-in things like `list`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex, you can use `string.split`:

```
if len(my_phrase.split()[2]) <=3:
    //process my_phrase
```

This works since there are spaces between the words.

Answer (score 0):

Since your separator is space, you don't need regex and you can do with python standard method `string.split()`.

```
ls = ['cyber attacks, 28', 'cyber attacks. A', 'cyber attacks, intrusions', 'cyber attacks; 3', 'cyber attack. Our',
      'cyber intrusions, data']

def my_filter(i) -> bool:
    sub_str = i.split(' ', 2)
    if len(sub_str) < 3:
        return False
    return len(sub_str[2]) <= 3

print([i for i in ls if my_filter(i)])
```